# Batch pattern replacement in file names

Tags: bash, command-line

I have stumbled many times upon this problem and I am curious to know if there is any command line mechanic I don't know that could solve it.

Let's consider I have a set of files, which I would like to rename, changing a prefix in the the name by another one.

Renaming:

```
foo_a.png
foo_b.png
foo_c.png
```

To:

```
bar_a.png
bar_b.png
bar_c.png
```

in a single command-line, not in a script.

---

**Below are a few explanations about what I know that get close to this.**

I know how to conveniently iterate on those files, for example to convert them to another format.

```
find . -name "foo*png" |xargs -I G mv G bar_G
```

This is actually kind of cheating as it reuses the old file name as part of the new file name.

---

Please detail the command used in your answer.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jm666 commented that you could use rename, can't beat that.
When you want to do this by hand and also support filenames with newlines in iy, writing this by hand will result in

```
find . -name foo\*png -print0 2>/dev/null |
xargs -0 -I G bash -c 'newfile=$(sed 's/foo/bar/' <<< "G") ; mv "G" "${newfile}"'
```

I think you will go for

```
rename foo bar foo*png
```

EDIT: The line with find was not formatted as code.
and
Explanation `find print0` + `xargs -0` (or `xargs -null`):
Filenames can have spaces and newlines. You can not parse the find output line-by-line when you want to handle filenames with newlines.
Example:

```
touch "an
> example"
find . -name an\* | xargs -I G echo "==G=="
==./an==
==example==
find . -name an\* -print0 | xargs -0 -I G echo "==G=="
==./an
example==
```

Comment: What does `-0` do? The "rename" need was actually kind of an example, in your problem brings a very generic solution that I can reuse for other use cases (when batch converting to another format for example). Thanks !